Forcing to dns over tls in linux /etc/resolve.conf ubuntu
I saw the post here about DNS over TLS with systemd-resolved. Is there a way to do the similar thing without having systemd-resolved installed? like DNS over TCP has this feature in /etc/resolve.conf
options use-vc

Is there similar things for TLS?
Edit --> I use ubuntu 24.04 LTS, and I have removed systemd-resolved myself.

@guiverc hi. I am new to the community so sorry for the mistake. I have uninstalled systemd-resolved from my system. That's why I'm hoping to do this via resolve.conf only

@guiverc I edited the post. Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1111592/1698042
